# Использование apple-touch-startup-image

Tags: html, ios, apple, safari

В Сафари можно добавлять иконки сайтов на рабочий стол, чтоб можно было иметь быстрый доступ к любимому сайту. В свою очередь наш любимый сайт должен сделать это добавление красивым и удобным.

Добавляем иконки приложений благодаря apple-touch-icon. Еще есть атрибут apple-touch-startup-image, который позволяет добавить "обложку", которая будет показываться перед запуском сохраненного веб-приложения.

Но вот незадача, добавляю

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup.png" />
```

в качестве startup.png - фотография 640x960px;

Сохранил иконку на рабочий стол, запускаю - а обложка не показалась. Подскажите, хешкодеры - в чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: На вскидку: что-нибудь типа "положить в корень сайта файл с названием apple-touch-startup-image.png и ок" не работает?

Comment: пятый айфон? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454208/how-to-set-apple-touch-startup-image-for-iphone5

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="img/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="img/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

http://www.favicon-generator.org/